# Can someone help me how to render immediately after the put and delete request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentProduct: null,
      items: [],
    };
    this.handlepostSubmit= this.handlepostSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products.json')
    .then(res => {
    const items = res.data;
    this.setState({ items });
  })}

  handlepostSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const product = {
    name: event.target[0].value,
    style_no: event.target[1].value,
    color: event.target[2].value,
    material: event.target[3].value,
    origin: event.target[4].value,
  };


  let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
  axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = token;
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json'

axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/${this.state.currentProduct.id}`, {product})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);

  })
}


  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

 axios.delete
 (`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/${this.state.currentProduct.id}`)
  .then(res => {

  })
}

render() {
  const products = []
  this.state.items.map(person => 
    products.push(person))

return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <Sidebar products={products} onSelect={product => this.setState({currentProduct: product})}/>
    </div>

    <div>
      <Form product={this.state.currentProduct} />
    </div>

    <div>
      <form  onSubmit={this.handlepostSubmit}>
        <label>Name:<input type="text" /></label>
        <label>Style_no:<input type="text"/></label>
        <label>Color:<input type="text"  /></label>
        <label>material<input type="text" /></label>
        <label>Orgin<input type="text" /></label>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
     </form>
   </div>
     <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Delete</button>
  </div>
);}}
export default App
```

Right now, I am facing difficulties with how to render the component after the put and delete request. In the code above, after I click the edit and delete button, it does not render on the page immediately. I have to refresh the page to get the new information. Can someone give me information how to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// APP COMPONENT

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Sidebar from './sidebar';
import Form from './form';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentProduct: null,
      products: [],
      name: '',
      styleNo: '',
      color: '',
      material: '',
      origin: '',
    };

    this.handlepostSubmit = this.handlepostSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleProductSelected = this.handleProductSelected.bind(this);
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
  }

  //   forceUpdateHandler(){
  //     this.forceUpdate();
  //   };

  handleChange(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(res => {
      const items = res.data;
      console.log(items);
      this.setState({ products: items });
    });
    // http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products.json
  }

  handlepostSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, styleNo, color, material, origin } = this.state;
    console.log('selected name ', name);
    const product = {
      name,
      style_no: styleNo,
      color,
      material,
      origin,
    };

    console.log(product);
    // let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
    // axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = token;
    // axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json'

    // axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/${this.state.currentProduct.id}`, {product})
    //   .then(res => {

    //   })
  }

  handleDelete(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('on delete');

    // axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/${this.state.currentProduct.id}`)

    //   .then(res => {

    //   })
  }

  //   forceUpdate =event=>{
  //     location.reload(true);
  //   }
  handleProductSelected(product) {
    this.setState({
      currentProduct: product,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { products } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Form product={this.state.currentProduct} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handlepostSubmit}>
            <label>
              Name:
              <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Style_no:
              <input type="text" name="styleNo" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Color:
              <input type="text" name="color" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              material
              <input type="text" name="material" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Orgin
              <input type="text" name="origin" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </form>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Sidebar products={products} onSelect={this.handleProductSelected} />
        </div>
      </div>`enter code here`
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

```
//Sidebar Component 

import React from 'react';

class SideBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(product) {
    const { onSelect } = this.props;
    onSelect(product);
  }

  render() {
    const { products } = this.props;
    return products.map(product => {
      // let boundItemClick = onItemClick.bind(this, x);
      return (
        <li key={product.id} onClick={() => this.handleClick(product)}>
          <p> {product.id} </p>
          {/* <p> {product.style_no}</p>
                <p> {product.color}</p> */}
        </li>
      );
    });
  }
}

export default SideBar;
```

```
import React from 'react';

class Form extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { product } = this.props;
    return (
      <section id="product">
        <p>selected product: {product ? product.id : 'no product'} </p>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: my case works, but it wont update immediately, you case is totol different than my way. I dont really understand. Sorry T.T

Comment: Check my new edit, Did that work? why are  pushing elements in an array? You could just grab the iitems from state ;)

Comment: is it possible to add those part in my code. I am confusing to look at that. sorry about that

Comment: No problem, reactjs is hard to understand. Yes, you could add those parts in your code. whenever you set state, react will update the UI for you,  Try it an experiment with that ;)

Comment: hello, can you take a look my put request, I do not know why when I console.log(res.data). it return empty

Comment: Could you add your code in an online editor like stackblitz?. https://stackblitz.com/ It's hard to see the code

Comment: https://codepen.io/cmsio/pen/gyJvgb?editors=1010
there is three component, which call sidebar, form, and app

Comment: I'll let you know!

Comment: @user10297590 I edited the post! check the code an experiment with it, I changed some data just to test it, but it is working now. I can explain when you check that it works! Let me know!

Comment: Why you comments out the delete and put method haha

Comment: it works, but i dont understand why my code is wrong. thank you

Comment: Great! could you mark it as correct? So I would recommend you to learn more about js and try to create this app with vanilla js, so you get a better understating of it. It's hard to explain here, because I changed most of your code.

Comment: do you have any contact information, react seems not like that easy, it need to consider all the states change

Comment: Join this slack to chat and when I have time I can explain the code better.   https://join.slack.com/t/tutoring-s6w8396/shared_invite/enQtNjIzNjIxOTg3Nzc2LWU4M2I0ODA3NDVjNmMyNWRkNzA3MDQwM2MwOWU5YWJjN2M4YWRkNDBjZTE1ZWI0ZWRjZTY2NzBiZjY1Yzg0MmU . Yeah react is kind of hard.